# perl regular expression to get the text between 5) some text 6)

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit

in the above example i was trying to get the text between 5) and 6) which is `On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway`

i have written following `5[)]\s?(.*?)6[)]\s?/i` but this is getting fail here as i have `(x86)` so my expression will match  `On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x8`

so i was thinking for adding `[^\/]` so it will skip `x86)\` but its not working out...can some one please help.

Comment: What is your general problem? A regex that will trivially solve your sample is ^5\\)(\s.*\s)6\\). It will fail most of the time on similar data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this question correctly, you want to match up to `6)` unless `6)` is part of the string `(x86)`. In that case, use a negative look-behind assertion:

```
/5\)\s?(.*?)(?<!\(x8)6\)\s?/i
```

which is to say, ... match up until `6)` unless it is `(x86)`.

Comment: hi mob just another question .. `5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x86)` in this example if i want to grep `on 32 bit (x86)` this is after 6) what shd i use .. i tried `m/6[)]\s?(.*)/i` but it grepped `6)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x86)` ...

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
5\)(.*?)\s6\)
```

I'm using the white space before the `6)` to get what you want, and this white space is not needed in your captured string, right?

Comment: so the white space was optional ... one in my pattern..it may or may not come in the string.

Comment: @Tanuj Could you perhaps give more examples of strings you might come across?

Comment: `5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x86)` this string is one of the example .. and white spaces here are optional.. it may or may not come in string...

Comment: So, if I understand well, you want to get `On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway` here? Or `On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x`? Note that my regex works with the first option I'm asking you.

Comment: i want to get `On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway` here

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($text) = /(?:\b\d+\))(.+?)(?:\s\d+\))/;
    print "$text\n";
}

__DATA__
5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit
42)even more text 43)I think
7)Twenty four (24) 8)
```

Output:

```
 On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway
even more text
Twenty four (24)
```

The regex's tries to first match a word boundary followed by one+ digits and then a right paren.  It then non-greedily captures all up to a whitespace followed by one+ digits and then a right paren.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Go simple `5\)(.*6\).*)6\)` should put it all in `$1`. Rather than exclude any surrounding white space in the regular expression I would use `trim($1)`.

One problem with trying to match the white space within the regular expression, for example with `5\)\s*(.*6\).*)\s*6\)` is knowing which part of the expression matches the space before the rightmost `6)`. Considering the `.*\s*6\)` part does the `.*` or `\s*` match the space in `text 6)`? Hence the suggestion to use trim.

Comment: This fails whenever there's another `6)` further to the right.  Whitespace is significant here.

Comment: There is only one `)6` in the question. But using a non-greedy `.*?` should suffice.

Comment: @AdrianHHH read the question well please. There are two `6)`, one in `(x86)` and another one later.

Comment: this will fail if i have something like `5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x86)` this pattern will match `5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x8`

Comment: if i go .*? greedy than it will match the one which i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Well spotted @Jerry, how about `5\)(.*6\).*)6\)`?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the "ungreedy" qualifier.

In other words, replace the capturing pattern

```
(.*?)
```

with

```
(.*)
```

The first will match as little as possible.
The second will match as much as possible.

Comment: this will fail if i have something like `5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x86)` this pattern will match `5) On 64bit OS go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common gateway 6) on 32 bit (x8`

Comment: Replace your closing match "6[)]\s?" with " 6[)]".  In other words, match the space here.  BTW, the trailing "\s?" does nothing, as it is both optional and non-capturing.

Comment: thanks ..@fisharebest i have removed form the last ..but my problem with getting the test between ... so is there a way i can have something like match 6) which is not followed my /